# Buying Ripple XRP with Bitcoin BTC

Tags: ripple, trade

I have Bitcoin in my Coinbase wallet.  I want to buy Ripple on another exchange since Coinbase does not trade Ripple.

Do I copy and paste my Bitcoin alphanumeric key code from Coinbase to the other exchange?
or
Do I hand write the Coinbase Bitcoin alphanumeric key code in the address window in the other exchange that trades Ripple in order to deposit my Coinbase Bitcoin into the other exchange so I can buy Ripple with Bitcoin?

Answer (score 2):

The usual process is this:

1. You create an account on the exchange.
2. You go through their menus to deposit bitcoins.
3. They give you an address to send bitcoins to.
4. You withdraw from Coinbase to that deposit address.
5. You wait about an hour.
6. You now have a bitcoin balance on that exchange that you can trade.

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://shapeshift.io/#/coins to convert your Bitcoin to Ripple and other cryptocurrencies.

Comment: I would suggest this, but you also have to have a Ripple wallet to store your bitcoins. Sorry I don't know much else about Ripple or a good wallet.

Answer (score 0):

For GateHub, I had to ask them to deposit 20 XRP into my account so I can begin trading in XRP. This is on top of buying BTC, LTC, or ETH first on CoinBase and then sending to GateHub exchange address for that specific altcoin.

Answer (score 0):

I set up a wallet for XRP on CRYPTONATOR, then used Changelly, which allows you to move your BTC or LTC or ETH from Coinbase into the XRP wallet. But first I think you need to move some ETH or BTC into a CRYPTONATOR wallet and use that to open the XRP wallet because you need to deposit at least 20 XRP to start the XRP wallet. Then you can use the XRP wallet id from CRYPTONATOR to set up a transfer id from Changelly (ie BTC to XRP then it asks your XRP wallet destination and gives you a transaction code).  It's kind of a hassle, but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a coinbase account then you just need to set up an account at an exchange, this [step by step guide shows the process of buying ripple using coinbase and binance](http://crypto-coin-guide.blogspot.co.uk/2018/01/how-to-buy-ripple-step-by-step-newbie.html).

Comment: Welcome to Bitcoin.SE! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.